# The xml is not switching when device orientation change

Tags: android, configuration, android-layout

I have made two folders, `res/layout` and `res/layout-land`

**The output i got**
If I start the application in `portrait` mode, it will always use the xml in `layout` folder if the application run in `portrait` mode. And will not use xml in `layout-land` if i change the device to `landscape` mode
If it start in `landscape` mode it only use the xml in `layout-land`
**The xml is not switching when the orientation change**

**What i expect was**
It should use the xml in `layout` folder while it is in portrait mode and use the xml in layout-land while in landscape mode

In the Manifest file i have added `android:configChanges="orientation"` for the activity and

```
<supports-screens 
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Did i missed any thing here? What changes i need to do here?
Thank You

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The manifest code

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

ignores the XML in "layout-land" and uses the one in the "layout" folder. If you create a different XML for landscape **don't** use the `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` tag for that activity.

Comment: Do you know how we can detect if orientation change happen in that case?
Without this setting onConfigurationChange is never called.

Comment: YOU ARE A LIFE SAVER TO ME! :)

Answer (score 24):

android:configChanges="orientation" stops the activity from restarting, so also from reloading the xml layout (you normally do this in onCreate).
Instead, onConfigurationChanged(newConfig) is called. So you can do:

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        setContentView(R.layout.<xml file>);
    }
```

This wil reload  the layout from the layout-land dir, if available.
Note: you will also need to link actions to buttons and things like that

Comment: what if I have fragments ?

Answer (score 2):

Do not forget to turn on `Settings -> Display -> Auto-rotate screen` option.

Comment: The problem isn't that the screen won't rotate at all. The problem is that the layout isn't changing.

Comment: @Zorpix You can't know what the author meant. I forgot to enable "Auto-rotate" in settings, and that's why I wrote this answer.

Comment: I don't mean to rudely dismiss your answer. I know slip ups like forgetting to turn on auto rotate happen. But that wouldn't cause the orientation to change but not change the XML like the original question stated.

Comment: Oh god, this in fact was the solution to my problem. So even if it does not address the issue of the original question, for google's sake I would leave this answer as is.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void setContentBasedOnLayout()
{
    WindowManager winMan = (WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

    if (winMan != null)
    {
        int orientation = winMan.getDefaultDisplay().getOrientation();

        if (orientation == 0) {
            // Portrait
            setContentView(R.layout.alertdialogportrait);
        }
        else if (orientation == 1) {
            // Landscape
            setContentView(R.layout.alertdialoglandscape);
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than only post a block of code, please *explain* why this code solves the problem posed. Without an explanation, this is not an answer.